# express static 2 different folders

Tags: node.js, express, static

Files:

[image]
I have two different frontend build apps, each one in own directory - **frontApp** and **frontAdmin** and I need to send them on different requests

in **routes/index.js**

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

router.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('admin/index.html');
});
```

I tried
in **app.js**

```
const frontPath = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontApp'));
const adminPath = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontAdmin'));
app.use(frontPath);
app.use('/admin', adminPath);
```

At the end i get the app on http://localhost:3000/admin/ but with errors
[image]

Comment: Are you serving /admin as a route handler or statically.  It seems you are trying to do both and you shouldn't be!

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: To help you solve your problem, we need to see an example of a `/main` url that expect to work via `express.static()` and we need to see exactly where the file you want served with that URL is in your file system.  Same thing for a `/admin` url.  That's the only way we can help you get things matched up so `express.static()` does what you want.  Also, "doesn't work for me" is NOT a useful description of the problem.  You need to describe exactly what happens and what debugging steps you tried.  Do you get a 404 error?  Do you get no response from the server?  Do you get the wrong file?

Comment: And, when showing us where the desired files are in the file system, show us exactly where they are located relative to the script that you are putting these routes in.

Comment: Reading your question again, are there just two files you're trying to serve here: `main/index.html` and `admin/index.html`?  Or are there a whole set of resources for each?  Your question does not currently contain enough information for anyone to answer other than guess what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok now my question should be better, i hope

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for incorrect question, the problem was in mime type

i did this and it works now

```
const frontPath = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontApp'));
const adminPath = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontAdmin'));
app.use(frontPath);
app.use(adminPath);
app.use('/admin', adminPath);
```